# Redirect json response to Ajax PUT into JSP to be parsed by EL

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, jsp

A bit of background first:
(I'm a student, so please bear with me.)
Using jQuery, I've formulated an Ajax PUT request to a REST web service.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "PUT",
    url: putURI,
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    headers: {          
        Accept : "application/json; charset=utf-8",         
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"   
    },
    success: function (){
        $.getJSON(baseURI, function(data){
             $.each(data, function (i, task) {
                 alert(task.description);
                 row = "<tr><td id='" + task.description + "'></td></tr>";
                 $("#tasksTableBody tr:last").after(row);
            });
        });
    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
        alert(request.responseText);
        alert(status);
        alert(error);
    }
});
```

If possible, I'd like to reroute the response to my JSP, where there are EL and jstl to create the rows of the table exactly where I want them.

```
<tbody id="tasksTableBody">
   <core:forEach items="${allTasks}" var="task">
   <tr>
      <td id="desc${task.id}">
          ${task.description}
      </td>
      <f:parseDate value="${duedate}" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" var="duedate" />
      <td id="due${task.id}" value=duedate>
          <f:parseDate value="${duedate}" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd"/>
      </td>
      <td id="done${task.id}" data-isDone="${task.isdone}">
          <core:set var="isdone" value="${task.isdone}"/>
          <core:if test="${isdone == true}">
             <img src="images/checked.png"/>
          </core:if>
      </td>
      <td>
         <img src="images/edit-icon.png" onclick="editItem(${task.id})" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <img src="images/delete.png" onclick="deleteItem(${task.id})" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </core:forEach>
  </tbody>
```

Is this even possible, or do I need to stick to the 'success' function and try to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Returning HTML as opposed to, say, JSON is a valid approach and often simpler than dealing with JSON on the client side.

Just have your controller/servlet handling the PUT forward to the JSP and then use JQuery to update some element with the returned HTML. So this would look something like:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "PUT",
    url: putURI,
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    headers: {          
        Accept : "application/json; charset=utf-8",         
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"   
    },
    success: function (html){
        $( "#results" ).append( html ); //append response to an element with id 'results'

        // or

        $( "#results" ).html( html ); //replace contents of element with id 'results'
    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
        alert(request.responseText);
        alert(status);
        alert(error);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Alan! You're right! Much easier. I was just getting hung up on generating html in a method. My gut feeling is that it's primitive, for some reason. I need to get over that.